# Django - In local server all work fine but in Postgres is filtering the bad a query

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, django-queryset

how are you? first of all sorry for my bad english.

I have a problem with my server in DigitalOcean. i have the server running in Django with postgres and in local i use SQLite.

In both i use Python 3.4 - in local windows and python 3.4.3 in DO Ubuntu with python 3.4.0

Have a problem filtering a query.

this is the model

```
# Create your models here.
class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    fk_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, verbose_name='Cliente')
    fk_store = models.ForeignKey(Store, verbose_name='Local')
    store_internal_order = models.CharField(verbose_name='Orden Interna',
                                            max_length=10,
                                            null=True,
                                            blank=True)
    sector = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Sector',
                                 choices=SECTOR_CHOICES,
                                 default=1)
    article = models.CharField(verbose_name='Dispositivo', max_length=20)
    serial = models.CharField(verbose_name='Serial', max_length=25)
    work = models.CharField(verbose_name='Trabajo', max_length=40)
    article_details = models.CharField(verbose_name='Detalles Artículo',
                                       max_length=255, blank=True)
    cash_advance = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Seña', max_digits=6,
                                       decimal_places=2,
                                       default=0)
    initial_price = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Precio', max_digits=6,
                                        decimal_places=2,
                                        default=0)
    service_cost = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Costo', max_digits=6,
                                       decimal_places=2,
                                       default=0)
    randpassw = models.CharField(default='12345', max_length=5, blank=True,
                                 null=True)
    warranty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name='Garantía',
                                                default=0,
                                                blank=True,
                                                null=True)
    last_status = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Estado',
                                      choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                                      default=1)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

this is the view

```
def index(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('auth_login')

    title = "Lista de Ordenes"
    # Creamos el query para tomar las ordenes
    queryset = WorkOrder.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.exclude(last_status=20)
    # Tomamos el filtro de sector
    sector_filter = request.GET.get('sector')
    # Tomamos filtro de ENTREGADAS
    # delivered = reqeust.GET.get('delivered')

    context = {
               'title': title,
              }

    if not request.user.is_staff:
        user_store = request.user.userprofile.fk_store
        # Añadimos otro filtro al queryset para tomar solo las del local
        # correspondiente al usuario
        queryset = queryset.filter(fk_store=user_store)
        store = Store.objects.get(name=user_store)

        context.update({'store': store})

    # Si hay un filtro de sector volvemos a filtrar el queryset
    if sector_filter:
        queryset = queryset.filter(sector=sector_filter)

    context.update({'queryset': queryset})

    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 7)  # Show 5 orders per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        orders = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If the page is not an integer, deliver first page
        orders = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        orders = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context.update({'orders': orders})

    return render(request, "workorders/index.html", context)
```

Well here is my problem i have to filter all the work orders that have in the Last Status the Status "20" (int)

In local work perfect! i can see all the orders except the orders with last status 20. But in production in DigitalOcean VPS with gunicorn running. The query only show the orders with last status 1 and is filtering all the other orders.

i try first with this queryset `queryset = WorkOrder.objects.filter(~Q(last_status=20))`and after that i change for the queryset that you can see in my view. Both work fine in local but not in production.

**EDIT: Add the queryset.query that i have in production**

Here is the print of the queryset.query in the console in production

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from work_order.models import WorkOrder
>>> queryset = WorkOrder.objects.all()
>>> queryset = queryset.exclude(last_status=20)
>>> print(queryset.query)
SELECT "work_order_workorder"."id", "work_order_workorder"."fk_client_id", "work_order_workorder"."fk_store_id", "work_order_workorder"."store_internal_order", "work_order_workorder"."sector", "work_order_workorder"."article", "work_order_workorder"."serial", "work_order_workorder"."work", "work_order_workorder"."article_details", "work_order_workorder"."cash_advance", "work_order_workorder"."initial_price", "work_order_workorder"."service_cost", "work_order_workorder"."randpassw", "work_order_workorder"."warranty", "work_order_workorder"."last_status", "work_order_workorder"."timestamp" FROM "work_order_workorder" WHERE NOT ("work_order_workorder"."last_status" = 20)
>>> queryset
[<WorkOrder: 3>, <WorkOrder: 4>, <WorkOrder: 5>, <WorkOrder: 7>, <WorkOrder: 8>, <WorkOrder: 9>, <WorkOrder: 11>, <WorkOrder: 12>, <WorkOrder: 13>, <WorkOrder: 14>, <WorkOrder: 15>, <WorkOrder: 16>, <WorkOrder: 17>, <WorkOrder: 18>, <WorkOrder: 19>, <WorkOrder: 20>, <WorkOrder: 21>, <WorkOrder: 42>, <WorkOrder: 43>, <WorkOrder: 23>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>>
```

**EDIT 2: Working Fine**
the code was right but postgre was moving the orders when i update the last status to the end of the list. i solved the problem adding `order_by('id')` in the queryset.

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: to ask an obvious question: are there items in your database where the last_status isn't 1?

Comment: Yes in fact the query only shows in production the items with last_status 1 and is filtering 2, 3,......,20.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems right. Try this

```
queryset = WorkOrder.objects.all().exclude(last_status=20)
```

Comment: Yes i think the code is right because in local works perfect i go yo try your suggestion in a few hours and told you what happend